# DevOps Agents Source IPs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am running jobs within Azure DevOps in the North Europe region with a Microsoft agent pool.  These jobs need to talk to some on-premise hosted services that are available via the internet and protected by an edge firewall.  I am looking to lock this connectivity down on the firewall to just the Microsoft source IPs that the agents could appear from, but am struggling to find reliable information on the required ranges.

I’ve been referring to this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4

and also the service tags list for Azure DevOps:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

But these doesn’t seem to correlate with the IPs that I actually see the agents connecting in on which are generally in the Microsoft public ranges:

- 108.140.0.0/14
- 138.91.0.0/16
- 4.224.0.0/12

Is there a ‘better’ set of documentation that I could refer to in order to understand the required ranges?

Comment: in dev ops portal theres a help tab at the top right, ask the virtual assistant hoping they will put you though to a person, or submit a support ticket in the azure portal, or contact Azure Support on twitter, is my advice

Comment: From the documentation you linked `The Service Tag or previously mentioned inbound IP addresses don't apply to Microsoft Hosted agents. `

Comment: Thanks @jikuja I missed that, makes sense now why they don't correlate.

Comment: And thanks @EnenDaveyBoy, I'll reach out to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detailed description here: [To identify the possible IP ranges for Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-ip-ranges)

1. Check your region.
2. Check your ips here: [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519)

Comment: Thanks, the issue I have with this though is that the documentation doesn't match my experience.  I am running in North Europe, so based on the "AzureDevOps.NorthEurope" service tag I should see the agent traffic coming from "20.166.41.0/24".

Instead however, I see the traffic coming from the prefixes that I listed in my original post, which according to the list aren't even associated to DevOps.